# How can I view all WP generated thumbnails in Media Manager?

Tags: plugin-development, media-library

When WP creates thumbnails from the original uploaded image, they are hidden from view inside the Media Manager listing. Can they be made visible, via some filter or action so that you can selectively edit/delete them?

Comment: Please explain more, are you saying when an image is uploaded as a thumbnail, ie. directly when creating a post and setting the featured image, that, this image is hidden from the media listing? If that's not the case, i'm not sure i follow, surely displaying thumbnails otherwise would result in duplicate media items, no?

Comment: @t31os - I would like to see every image that appears in the directory, even ones that appear to be duplicated. If WP created an image, I want to see it, just like I see in FTP. Make sense?

Answer (score 4):

**Notice**:

*I'm considering that by Media Manager you're referring to the Media Library.*

```
/wp-admin/media.php
```

---

Maybe [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) could handle this, but won't get there...

I'd propose an alternative solution that prevents seeing ***lots*** of duplicates in the Media Library page:

[image]

The output of the `All Thumbs` column is simply a link to the image.
But I think it can be easily adapted to include at least a *delete capability*, using [some PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+unlink).

It could also be coupled with jQuery behavior control and CSS styling...

```
if( is_admin() )
{
    add_filter( 'manage_upload_columns', 'wpse_7757_all_thumbs_column_register' );
    add_action( 'manage_media_custom_column', 'wpse_7757_all_thumbs_columns_display', 10, 2 );
}

function wpse_7757_all_thumbs_column_register( $columns ) 
{
    $columns['all_thumbs'] = 'All Thumbs';

    return $columns;
}

function wpse_7757_all_thumbs_columns_display( $column_name, $post_id ) 
{
    if( 'all_thumbs' != $column_name || !wp_attachment_is_image($post_id) )
        return;

    $full_size = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id, 'full' );
    echo '<div style="clear:both">FULL SIZE : '.$full_size[1].' x '.$full_size[2].'</div>';

    $size_names = get_intermediate_image_sizes();

    foreach( $size_names as $name )
    {
        // CHECK THIS: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_get_attachment_image_src-problem
        $the_list = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_id, $name );

        if ( $the_list[3] )
            echo '<div style="clear:both"><a href="'.$the_list[0].'" target="_blank">'.$name.'</a> : '.$the_list[1].' x '.$the_list[2].'</div>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just go to `Dashboard -> Media -> Library`? From there, you can see *every* image in the Media Library, and can perform some bulk operations, etc.