# Display thumbnail only if requested size exists

Tags: post-thumbnails, images

When I use the functions that get and output the post thumbnail, they will display the requested thumbnail in the size you specify, but if this size doesn't exist they will display the thumbnail in the original size and force the browser to resize it.

How can I force them to display a placeholder like "no image" in case the requested size doesn't exist?

Comment: Are you talking about registered thumbnail sizes or you are trying to get arbitrary non-registered size in pixels? Code example please?

Comment: about the registered sizes

Answer (score 2):

**Assuming** the question is about `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.
<sub>It could be also about `wp_get_attachment_link`, but, although related, this analysis doesn't includes it.</sub>

---

**Got aware** of this issue answering this question: [How can I view all WP generated thumbnails in Media Manager?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/7757/12615).
<sub>Refer to it to see a working code regarding the issue *on this Question*.</sub>

And it lead to this [WordPress forum topic](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp_get_attachment_image_src-problem).

---

The function [wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, $size, $icon )](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src) returns an array containing:

```
[0] => url  
[1] => width  
[2] => height  
[3] => is intermediate
```

If `[3]` is false, the `original` image data is returned.

---

**Both** `wp_get_attachment_image_src` and `wp_get_attachment_link` rely in the function `image_downsize`, inside `/wp-includes/media.php`.
And that's where this 4 items array is being returned.

Answer (score 1):

I'm Not sure about this but i know you can use php's getimagesize() function
something like this:

```
//This must be in one loop

if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    $wanted_width = 300;
    $wanted_height = 150;
    $id = get_post_thumbnail_id()
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($id);
    if ($image){
        list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image[0]);
        if (($wanted_height = $width) && ($wanted_height = $height)){
            the_post_thumbnail();
        }
        else{
            //default when no image
            echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/img-default.png" />';
        }
    }
    else{
        //default when no image
        echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/img-default.png" />';
    }
} else {
    //default when no image
    echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/img-default.png" />';
}
```

and i know it's not an answer to the question directly but you can use a plugin called  [AJAX Thumbnail Rebuild](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ajax-thumbnail-rebuild/) -
This plugin allows you to re-build the post thumbnails. Useful if you add_image_size() after already having uploaded post thumbnails.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I was able to display a thumbnail only if a requested size exists:

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() )  {
    $imgdata = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'thumbnail' ); //change thumbnail to whatever size you are using
    $imgwidth = $imgdata[1]; // thumbnail's width                   
    $wanted_width = 300; //change this to your liking
    if ( ($imgwidth < $wanted_width ) ) {
        the_post_thumbnail();
    } else { 
        //do whatever you want
    }
}
```

[To learn more about `wp_get_attachment_image_src` read the Codex.](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src)

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin that will actually create the image size automatically for you if it doesn't exist. http://austinmatzko.com/wordpress-plugins/filosofo-custom-image-sizes/

I haven't needed to use this plugin yet myself. But it's worth a shot. There is talk about adding similar functionality to WP core, maybe in 3.2 http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15311

Answer (score 0):

It's seem's to be a better way. 
Use the global variable $_wp_additional_image_sizes, it's store all registered image_size.
So if you want to check if an image size name is define :

```
  global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
  if ( array_key_exists( 'desired-image-size' , $_wp_additional_image_sizes) )
  {
    //your code here
  }
  else
  {
    //default code here 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to use Wordpress' built-in "get_intermediate_image_sizes" function to return the full list of image sizes as an array then look through that.

```
show_image_by_size( 10470, 'custom_size' );

function show_image_by_size( $_post_id, $_desired_size ) {
  $_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
  $_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $_post_id );
  $_image_size = ( in_array( $_desired_size , $_sizes ) ) ? $_desired_size : 'full';
  $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $_thumbnail_id, $_image_size );
  echo '<img src="' . esc_url( $image[0] ) . '" />';
}
```

Comment: You assume that, just because a size is defined in the theme or via a plugin, it also has a generated thumbnail, which is a wrong assumption.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this will help

```
<?php 
//This must be in a loop
if(has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
} else {
    echo '<img src="'.get_bloginfo("template_url").'/images/img-default.png" />';
}
?>
```

from: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_post_thumbnail
I use something like this to check if the image size exists:

```
if (function_exists('has_post_thumbnail') && has_post_thumbnail('medium')) {
//// code to display thumbnail goes here
}
else {
/// otherwise do this
}
```

Hope it helps get you going.